# Make Something Disappear In Certain Browser

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

I have an img src on my website, and I noticed a cross-browser compatibility issues. I know there's a way to detect browsers with JavaScript, but is there a way to make it so that the image disappears in Internet Explorer and Firefox? It seems to work just fine in google chrome.

Comment: We can't see your code over the seas and mountains high...

Comment: can you be a little more specific? show your current code?

Comment: Why don't you post the actual HTML/JS and let us help you solve the actual cross browser problem rather than just asking for a way to hide the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it as default-hidden, then show it again using WebKit-specific CSS:

```css
#someImage {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    #someImage {
        display: inline; /* Or whatever else you may have set it to */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for IE:

```
<!--[if IE 8]> <link href="/ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <link href="/ie9.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <![endif]-->
```

for FireFox

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    #my-id { display:none; }
}
```

Comment: Not quite what he's asking...read again. Nice solution to another question though :p